# Chrome 40 beta Title Tabs Rendering With Serif-style Font

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fonts

I've noticed an interesting anomaly when running Chrome 40.0.2214.10 beta-m (64-bit) on Win7. Admittedly, I have yet to test this on other browsers.

In the screenshot below you will see to eBay item pages -- the first has a title which renders as a Serif (is that Times New Roman) in the Chrome Title Tab. The latter renders in the standard Sans-Serif Chrome font.

[image]

The URL for the first example is here: http://ebay.com/itm/301399607776

My principle question is whether or not this is something that I can reproduce using any combination of markup, javascript or other file or server-side settings -- or whether or not this is some kind of unusual bug or setting in my local browser settings.

Comment: I'm leaning towards the TM character being the culprit here, although I would like to verify this.

Comment: It happens to this article for me too: http://alistapart.com/article/every-time-you-call-a-proprietary-feature-css3-a-kitten-dies

Comment: I copy-pasted the title characters into a google search and that title bar is even doing it!

Comment: It looks like the TM character and a hidden character in that ALA article are from [this Unicode block](http://www.fontspace.com/unicode/block/C1+Controls+and+Latin-1+Supplement). Must be a Chrome bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug with certain characters in Chrome, if you copy and paste (for example, into a Chrome URL bar):

Mens Mickey Mouse T Shirt

You will see the rendering issue appear in the Input Form. (Note: the character `U+0091` appears between the "n" and "s" in "Mens" here.)